# Document.select("a[href]") not getting all the href

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSOUP to fetch the documents from a website.

Below is my code

```
webPageUrl = https://mwcc.ms.gov/#/electronicDataInterchange
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webPageUrl).get();  
Elements links = doc.getElementsByAttribute("a[href]");
```

Below line of code is not working. It is supposed to return an element but doesn't:

```
doc.getElementsByAttribute("a[href]")
```

Can someone please point out the mistake in my code?

Comment: The `#` in the address is a good indicator that your page is being dynamically generated in the browser with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

That page seems to be an Angular application, which means it loads some (probably all or most) of its content via JavaScript scripts.

The fact that the URL contains the fragment separator `#` is already a strong indicator of that fact, because if you do a HTTP request, then everything after that indicator is cut off (i.e. not sent to the server), so the actual request will just be of `https://mwcc.ms.gov/`.

As far as I know JSoup does not support running JavaScript, so you might need to look into a more involved scraping tool (possibly running a full browser engine).